# LINQ to Entities: queryable extension method not reconized inside where condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i am using asp.net 4.5 mvc 5 with code first entity framework and have the following issue:

i have two models, "PostBody" and "PostHeader". 1 PostHeader has 1-n PostBodies.
A PostBody can be "Deleted" (Property as flag).

My extension method should give me every PostBody from an IQueryable-Object which is not deleted as an IQueryable:

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> GetActiveVersions<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
       where TSource : PostBody
    {
        return source.Where(x => x.Deleted == false);
    }
```

this is working fine when i do somethin like this

```
var x = db.Bodies.GetActiveVersions().ToList();
```

or this

```
var y = db.Headers.FirstOrDefault().Bodies.AsQueryable().GetActiveVersions().ToList();
```

etc. - But as soon as i use my extension method as part of an expression paramater within e.g. the where method, i'm running into a NotSupportedException:

```
var z = db.Headers.Where(h => h.Bodies.AsQueryable().GetActiveVersions().Count() > 0).ToList();

System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WebApplication5.Models.PostBody] GetActiveVersions[PostBody](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WebApplication5.Models.PostBody])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

what am i doing wrong? or - how can i use my extension method within the where condition?

Comment: The easiest way to think of this is that Entity Framework wants to run logic directly against the database. It can only do that when our queries are made up by expressions. Once you make a new IQueryable, it's unable to figure out the logic to make the right T-SQL.

Comment: If the `GetActiveVersions` contains some logic EF understands (in this case it is `Where(x => x.Deleted = false)`, then use that logic **directly** on the query. Once you put that logic in a separate custom method, no matter what it's extension method or not, it then won't understand the method any more. Even when the method body is just simple and totally can be understood by EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the parser cannot resolve the extension method in the linq expression. You could try to centralize your condition and use it as a expression tree, for sample:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> GetActiveVersions()
    where TSource : PostBody
{
  return x => x.Deleted == false;
}
```

And apply this expressin in your subquery (with linq) for sample:

```
var z = db.Headers.Where(h => h.Bodies.AsQueryable().Any(GetActiveVersions())).ToList();
```

Instead using the `Count() > 0`, prefer using `.Any()` to avoid to access all records of the table.